# Let $m,n$ be natural numbers. Then prove the commutativity of the product $n\times m = m\times n$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

Let $m,n$ be natural numbers. Then $n\times m = m\times n$.

**MY ATTEMPT (EDIT)**

**Lemma 1**

We shall need first the following result: $m\times 0 = 0$.

Let us prove it by induction on $m$. Indeed, one has that $0\times 0 = 0$, by the definition of multiplication by $0$ on the left. Let us assume the proposition holds for $m$, that is to say, $m\times 0 = 0$, and we shall prove it to $m\texttt{+}\texttt{+}$. Indeed, one has
\begin{align*}
(m\texttt{+}\texttt{+})\times 0 = (m\times 0) + 0 = 0 + 0 = 0
\end{align*}

And we are done.

**Lemma 2**

We shall prove that $m\times(n\texttt{+}\texttt{+}) = m\times n + m$ by induction on $m$.

To start with, notice that $0\times(n\texttt{+}\texttt{+}) = 0 = 0\times n + 0$, and the base case is done. Let us assume that $m\times(n\texttt{+}\texttt{+}) = m\times n + m$, and prove it holds that $(m\texttt{+}\texttt{+})\times(n\texttt{+}\texttt{+}) = (m\texttt{+}\texttt{+})\times n + m\texttt{+}\texttt{+}$:
\begin{align*}
(m\texttt{+}\texttt{+})\times(n\texttt{+}\texttt{+}) & = m\times(n\texttt{+}\texttt{+}) + n\texttt{+}\texttt{+} = m\times n  + m + n \texttt{+}\texttt{+}\\\\
& = (m\times n + n\texttt{+}\texttt{+}) + m = (m\times n + n)\texttt{+}\texttt{+} + m\\\\
& = ((m\texttt{+}\texttt{+})\times n)\texttt{+}\texttt{+} + m = ((m\texttt{+}\texttt{+})\times n + m)\texttt{+}\texttt{+}\\\\
& = (m\texttt{+}\texttt{+})\times n + m\texttt{+}\texttt{+}
\end{align*}
And we are done.

**Proposition**

Based on the previous result, we shall prove the proposed statement by induction on $n$. According to **lemma 1**, one has that $0\times m = m\times 0 = 0$. Let us assume that $n\times m = m\times n$ and let us prove it for $n\texttt{+}\texttt{+}$. Second **lemma 2**, we have that
\begin{align*}
(n\texttt{+}\texttt{+})\times m = n\times m + m = m\times n + m = m\times(n\texttt{+}\texttt{+})
\end{align*}

And we are done.

Any comments or contributions on the solution?

Comment: Everything you've written is correct. Remember you want to prove $(n++)\times m=m\times(n++)$. So we compute both sides to verify the equality: you already computed $(n++)\times m$, on the other hand $m\times(n++)=m\times n+m$.

Comment: The problem consists in the fact that such property hasn't been proven yet.

Comment: In the argument above I didn't use that property. What I tried to say is: Let's say we want to prove $a=b$, where $a$ and $b$ are expressions or whatsoever. One way to go is to prove $a=c$ and $b=c$ so that we can now conclude $a=b$. I hope I'm making myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

$(n++)\times m=(n\times m)+ m = (m\times n)+m=m+(m\times n)=m\times (n++)$

Comment: The thing is that it hasn't been proven that $(n\texttt{+}\texttt{+})\times m = m\times(n\texttt{+}\texttt{+})$ yet.